# When an XPage is first loaded via a URL which JSF phases are used?

Tags: jsf, xpages

When a user accesses an XPage for the first time is the JSF lifecycle phase 6 (Render Response) the only phase that is executed? Is executed the correct term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET vs. POST requests are handled differently.  GET' require the least amount of processing (createView / restoreView [aka. Phase 1 - RESTORE_VIEW] followed by renderResponse [aka. Phase 6 - RENDER_RESPONSE].

The XPages Core Runtime does indeed build upon JSF... but there are differences in how the Request Processing Lifecycle is executed - XPages provides optimizations to deal with complex Ajax handling, complex Partial Execution and so on.  Effectively Phase 1 for a GET request does perform the createView/restoreView functions but bypasses some of the phase listening/notification steps to ensure the maximum throughput for a GET request.

I provided a simple example on OpenNTF.org / XSnippets to help people examine / practice with the XPages Request Processing Lifecycle under different circumstances.  I encourage you to look at:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xpages-request-processing-lifecycle-explorer-code...

Comment: Tony - the reason in fact I asked this question was after looking at the XPages lifecycle example you shared. I noticed that the phase listeners were not in fact being logged.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** [Here](http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=20B35C7A5E88ACD3852578CB006690E7) someone explains his observations regarding the XPages lifecycle. He made tests by himself because of a lack of documentation. Maybe it's a bit old.

I don't know for sure but XPages bases on JSF so I would suggest that **all** JSF-phases get cycled through:

```
Restore View -> Apply Request Values -> Process Validations -> Update Model Values -> Invoke Application -> Render Response
```

[image]

But there are for sure ways to interrupt those phases.

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on initial page load it skips directly to Render Response. Which makes sense when you consider the job of the other phases. There's no data to be validated, because the user hasn't had a chance yet to submit any; they also can't have invoked any events, etc. So the first request just renders, and subsequent requests go through the full lifecycle unless validation fails or is skipped.

And yes, "executed" is the correct term. :)